# Parallel Iterator

Tags: java, parallel-processing, iterator

I've looked through these forums to give me insight on how to create a ParallelIterator, but no luck. I want one Collection to be on one Thread and the another Collection to be on another Thread, but I wish to use a ThreadPool to do the job so that it can split up into parts equal to the amount of cores you have using Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(). I also want to return an Actor rather than a Collection of Actors but the next() method is stopping me from doing so. Here is my code so far:

```
package com.atem.util;

public class ParallelIterator<Collection<Actor>> implements Iterator<Collection<Actor>> {

    private Iterator<Actor> firstActorIterator;
    private Iterator<Actor> secondActorIterator;

    public ParallelIterator(final Collection<Actor> firstCollection, final Collection<Actor> secondCollection) {
        this.firstActorIterator = firstCollection.iterator();
        this.secondActorIterator = secondCollection.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.getFirstActorIterator().hasNext() && this.getSecondActorIterator().hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Actor> next() {
        return new ParallelCollection(this.getFirstActorIterator().next(), this.getSecondActorIterator().next());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        this.getFirstActorIterator().remove();
        this.getSecondActorIterator().remove();
    }

    public Iterator<Actor> getFirstIterator() {
        return this.firstIterator;
    }

    public Iterator<Actor> getSecondIterator() {
        return this.secondIterator;
    }

    public ParallelCollection<Actor> getParallelActorCollection() {
        return this.parallelActorCollection;
    }
}
```

I could change the next() method to return an Actor but then the ParallelCollection would get in the way. If there's anything else you wish to know, please let me know. Help is very much appreciated. Also, I'm somewhat of a beginner so if you could explain it in simple terms that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this yourself rather than e.g. using the very carefully designed utilities in e.g. Java 8?

Comment: I like trying it out by myself for learning reasons.

Comment: Why not start by copying the code which works already?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Louis's comment that you shouldn't try to write something like this on your own, but I wrote something that might help you get started.

**WARNING**: This code was not thoroughly tested:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Parallel {

    //modify the arg for the number of threads you want to use
    final static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    public static interface Operation<R, E> {
        public R perform(E input);
    }

    public static <R, E> List<R> forEach(final Iterable<E> inputs,
                                         final Operation<R,E> operation) {


        final List<Future<R>> futures = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Future<R>>());

        for (final E input : inputs) {
            final Callable<R> callable = new Callable<R>() {
                public R call() throws Exception {
                    return operation.perform(input);
                }
            };
            futures.add(service.submit(callable));
        }

        final List<R> outputs = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            for (final Future<R> future : futures) {
                outputs.add(future.get());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outputs;

    }
}
```